# why isnt my IF statement being executed correctly?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, printf

Im relatively new to python so i apologise if the answer is pretty straightforward. I am writing a basic script to allow users to enter different race participants from which the code will put these entries into a list. There is a minimum of 4 entries. After 4 entries it will ask if you would like to sort the list in ascending order. I have tested this and it works fine. There is a maximum of 8 entries, if this limit is reached it should ask the user for a final time to sort the list and it will be printed. When choosing yes on the 8th entry the sorted list is printed. However when choosing no, the list is supposed to be printed UNSORTED, but for some reason it is currently just ending the loop.

```
Race_participants = []

Mworldrec = 9.58
Meuropeanrec = 9.86
Mbritishrec = 9.87
Fworldrec = 10.49
Feuropeanrec = 10.73
Fbritishrec = 10.99


while len(Race_participants) < 8:
    
    name = str(input("\nWhat is the participants name? ")).lower()
    
    gender = str(input("\nIs the participant male or female? ")).lower()
    
    time = int(input("\nWhat is the participants race time? "))

    records_beaten = []

    if gender == "male":
        if Mworldrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens world record")
        if Meuropeanrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens european record")
        if Mbritishrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens British record")
        
    else:
        if Fworldrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens world record")
        if Feuropeanrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens european record")
        if Fbritishrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens British record")

    if records_beaten:
        print("\nParticipant", name,"has beaten the following records: ")
        for record in records_beaten:
            print("\n", record)
    
    print("\nParticipant" ,name, "Successfully recorded")

    def get_name(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('name')

    def get_gender(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('gender')

    def get_time(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('time')
        
    person = {
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'time': time

        }
    
    Race_participants.append(person)

    
    if len(Race_participants) >= 4:
        user_choice = input("Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)").lower()

        if user_choice == "yes":
            Race_participants.sort(key=get_time)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,Race_participants)

        elif user_choice == "no":
            continue

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")

    if len(Race_participants)== 8:
        print("You have reached the maximum amount of entries")
        user_choice = input("\nDo you want to sort the list? (yes/no)").lower()
        
        if user_choice == "yes":
            Race_participants.sort(key=get_time)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,Race_participants)

        elif user_choice == "no":
            print(Race_participants)

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
```

I have tried adding a seperate print function incase it is related to the logic of my list however i didnt think it would be considering the sorted version was able to be printed. After doing so, the test print function also didnt print, when choosing no, it simply ends the loop.

Comment: Which "if" statement do you mean is not executed correctly?

Comment: Look at your check for `user_choice`.  What does it do if it's `"no"`?  It excutes a `continue` statement.  That immediately ends the current loop iteration and starts the next loop iteration.  So of course it doesn't print anything.  You need to print the unsorted list before continuing.  In fact, you probably don't want the `continue` at all, since it will skip the code that follows.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `pass` rather then `continue`?

Comment: `input()` returns a string so there's no need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 3):

Let's "run" an instance of your code in our heads to see what's going on. Imagine that you've entered 8 race participants so far. Your code is now at this if statement:

```
    if len(Race_participants) >= 4:
        user_choice = input("Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)").lower()
```

Let's say you enter `no`. Your code then jumps to this line:

```
        elif user_choice == "no":
            continue
```

The `continue` forces the while loop to restart. You've told the while loop to end after it's reached 8 participants, so it ends. It never reaches the second statement that checks `if len(Race_participants) == 8`.

A better way to structure this code would be to first check `if len(Race_participants) == 8`, then `elif len(Race_participants) >= 4`.

Bonus tip: don't define functions inside of a while loop. Although it may technically not be raising you any errors, it is repulsive etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 reason the list isn't printed.

the first reason would be your if statements conditions are limitless, so it will always run the code once the length of the Race_participants list is greater than 4.

```
if len(Race_participants) >= 4:
```

Which brings us to the issue in that code block. where if you type "no" the keyword 'continue' is ran which end the current iteration in the while loop.
(so it skips the reset of the code and starts the loop again.)

```
elif user_choice == "no":
            continue
```

The reason the loop ends is because the conditions you passed to the while loop get fullfilled. (the length of Race_participants is no longer less than 8)

```
while len(Race_participants) < 8:
```

A simple fix to this problem would be to use the keyword pass instead of continue that way it goes through the entire loop.

```
elif user_choice == "no":
                pass
```

but than you are presented with another problem the final loop will run both if statements and print the message (Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)no) twice.

```
Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)no

You have reached the maximum amount of entries

Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)no
```

You would than have to change the conditions on you first if statement to something like the condition below which will prevent it from running on the last loop.

```
if len(Race_participants) >= 4 and len(Race_participants) < 8:
```

Here is a version I wrote. I tried to make minimal changes to the original code so you can compare them and get a better understanding of the concept.

I will try to explain where you when wrong.

```
# Write function outside the while loop.
def sort_participant(participants: list):
    """

    Sorts a list of dictionarys by the time key ascending order
    """

    sorted_list = sorted(participants, key=lambda k: k['time'])

    return sorted_list


race_participants = []

men_records = {"worldRecord":9.58, "europeanRecord":9.86, "britishRecord":9.87}

female_record = {"worldRecord":10.49, "europeanRecord":10.73, "britishRecord":10.99}

while len(race_participants) < 8:

    name = str(input('\nParticipants name: ')).capitalize()

    gender = str(input('\nGender [male/female]: ')).lower()

    time = float(input('\nRace time: '))

    # Check if records have been beaten

    records_beaten = []
    
    # Using a for loop to compare the records.
    if gender == "male":
        for key, value in men_records.items():
            if value > time:
                records_beaten.append(key)

    if gender == "female":
        for key, value in men_records.items():
            if value > time:
                records_beaten.append(key)

    print("\nParticipant" ,name, "Successfully recorded")

    # print any beaten records
    if records_beaten:
        print("\nParticipant", name,"has beaten the following records: ")
        for record in records_beaten:
            print("\n", record)
    
    # Save credentials to dict
    person = {
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'time': time
        }
    
    race_participants.append(person)
    
    if len(race_participants) >=4 and len(race_participants) < 8:
        
        while True:
            user_choice = input("Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no):").lower()

            if user_choice == "yes" or user_choice == "no":
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")

        if user_choice == "yes":
            sorted_list = sort_participant(race_participants)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,sorted_list)
            break
            

    if len(race_participants) == 8:

        print("\nYou have reached the maximum amount of entries")

        while True:
            user_choice = input("Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no):").lower()

            if user_choice == "yes" or user_choice == "no":
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
        
        # print sorted participant list
        if user_choice == "yes":
            sorted_list = sort_participant(race_participants)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,sorted_list)
            break

        # prints the unsorted participant list.
        elif user_choice == "no":
            print(race_participants)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... when choosing no, the list is supposed to be printed UNSORTED, but for some reason it is currently just ending the loop. ..."*

This is because the following *conditional-statement* will match when *Race_participants* is *8*.

```py
if len(Race_participants) >= 4:
```

Consequently, if the user enters *no*, it will *continue* the *loop* which is *conditional* to *len(Race_participants) < 8*.
Thus, no list is printed.

```py
elif user_choice == "no":
    continue
```

Try adding an additional check.

```py
if len(Race_participants) >= 4 and len(Race_participants) != 8
```

Or, just iterate on a *range*.

```py
for i in range(1, 9):
    if i == 4:
    elif i == 8:
```

Additionally, make a copy of *Race_participants* when sorting.

```py
copy = list(Race_participants)
copy.sort(key=get_time)
print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,copy)
```

Here is a re-factor.

```py
Race_participants = []

Mworldrec = 9.58
Meuropeanrec = 9.86
Mbritishrec = 9.87
Fworldrec = 10.49
Feuropeanrec = 10.73
Fbritishrec = 10.99

for i in range(1, 9):
    name = str(input("\nWhat is the participants name? ")).lower()

    gender = str(input("\nIs the participant male or female? ")).lower()

    time = int(input("\nWhat is the participants race time? "))

    records_beaten = []

    if gender == "male":
        if Mworldrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens world record")
        if Meuropeanrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens european record")
        if Mbritishrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("mens British record")

    else:
        if Fworldrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens world record")
        if Feuropeanrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens european record")
        if Fbritishrec > time:
            records_beaten.append("womens British record")

    if records_beaten:
        print("\nParticipant", name,"has beaten the following records: ")
        for record in records_beaten:
            print("\n", record)

    print("\nParticipant" ,name, "Successfully recorded")

    def get_name(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('name')

    def get_gender(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('gender')

    def get_time(Race_participants):
        return Race_participants.get('time')

    person = {
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'time': time

    }

    Race_participants.append(person)

    if i == 4:
        user_choice = input("Do you want to sort the list? (yes/no)").lower()

        if user_choice == "yes":
            copy = list(Race_participants)
            copy.sort(key=get_time)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,copy)

        elif user_choice == "no":
            continue

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
    elif i == 8:
        print("You have reached the maximum amount of entries")
        user_choice = input("\nDo you want to sort the list? (yes/no)").lower()

        if user_choice == "yes":
            copy = list(Race_participants)
            copy.sort(key=get_time)
            print("Sorted list in ascending order" ,copy)

        elif user_choice == "no":
            print(Race_participants)

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
```